# Wrong results of noisy optimization in r and mlrMBO

Tags: r, optimization, bayesian, mlr

i have a *noisy optimization* task. I try to find parameters of a function (which assets to choose and their weights) so that they will minimize function result (tracking error - a difference between portfolio and index returns). Financial terms are not really crucial to find a solution imo.

When i use optimization from `mlrMBO` the result (y) is always far away from theoretical and expected from intuition result. Result from `mbo` is even different from the same result with *optimal* parameters used in a function.

I tried changing learners, settings of the paramset and recoding the function but it does not work

Here is a minimal **reproducible** example ( the results are the same and the problem persists so i guess it is reproducible)

```r
max_stocks <- 10 # maximum number of assets to choose

# for the sake of reproducibility below is a provisional matrix of assets returns, each column is a different asset and stock index returns
quarter.pool <- matrix(rnorm(1830, 0, 0.01), nrow = 61, ncol = 300) 
stock_index <- matrix(rnorm(61,0,0.02))

# function with 2 inputs of same length vectors and tracking error as output
obj_func <- function(stock_weights, which_stocks){

  quarter.pool_ <- quarter.pool[,which_stocks] #choosing which assets to invest in
  portfolio <- matrix(rep(0,nrow(quarter.pool_))) # empty index-tracking portfolio

  for (i in 1:nrow(quarter.pool_)) {
    portfolio[i] <- sum(quarter.pool_[i,]*stock_weights, na.rm = TRUE)}

  tracking_error <- sqrt(sum(portfolio-stock_index)^2/length(portfolio-1))
  return(tracking_error)}

obj_f <- makeSingleObjectiveFunction(name = "index_tracking",
                                     fn = obj_func, 
                                     par.set = makeParamSet( makeNumericVectorParam("stock_weights", len = max_stocks, lower = 0, upper = 0.25),
                                                             makeIntegerVectorParam("which_stocks", len = max_stocks, lower = 1, upper = ncol(quarter.pool))), 
                                     noisy = TRUE, 
                                     vectorized = TRUE)

ctrl <-  makeMBOControl(final.method = "best.true.y", propose.points = 1)
ctrl <- setMBOControlTermination(ctrl, iters = 20, target.fun.value = 0.0000001)

run <- mbo(fun = obj_f, control = ctrl)

obj_func(run$x$stock_weights, run$x$which_stocks) == run$y 
# the result is different even tho function works as usual
```

the results vary a lot wherever i repeat the script. 
But the main problem is twofold:

> 1. It should be close to 0 and usually doesnt go even below 0.2. Dont even know if its possible.
> 2. The "optimal" y from `mbo` differ from results of putting "optimal" parameters into the same function. Maybe is it because the y is predicted and not real? although the difference is high.

**EDIT[1]**
Apparently when i deleted parameter "which_stocks" everything is good, so it must be because of it. Still is there any way to have it? Maybe the algorithm justcant handle that hard task?

Comment: Remark regarding the setup: The dimensionality might be a bit too high for this MBO setup. Also the function is deterministic and not noisy. If it was noisy you should change `best.true.y` to `best.predicted.y` to not select a point that has just randomly good performance.

Answer (score 1):

Please see my comments regarding the setup. Technically it works by passing the parameters as a list and add `has.simple.signature = FALSE` to the smoof wrapper.

```
max_stocks <- 10 # maximum number of assets to choose

# for the sake of reproducibility below is a provisional matrix of assets returns, each column is a different asset and stock index returns
quarter.pool <- matrix(rnorm(1830, 0, 0.01), nrow = 61, ncol = 300) 
stock_index <- matrix(rnorm(61,0,0.02))

# function with 2 inputs of same length vectors and tracking error as output
obj_func <- function(x){
  stock_weights = x$stock_weights
  which_stocks = x$which_stocks
  quarter.pool_ <- quarter.pool[,which_stocks] #choosing which assets to invest in
  portfolio <- matrix(rep(0,nrow(quarter.pool_))) # empty index-tracking portfolio

  for (i in 1:nrow(quarter.pool_)) {
    portfolio[i] <- sum(quarter.pool_[i,]*stock_weights, na.rm = TRUE)}

  tracking_error <- sqrt(sum(portfolio-stock_index)^2/length(portfolio-1))
  return(tracking_error)}

obj_f <- makeSingleObjectiveFunction(name = "index_tracking",
                                     fn = obj_func, 
                                     par.set = makeParamSet( makeNumericVectorParam("stock_weights", len = max_stocks, lower = 0, upper = 0.25),
                                                             makeIntegerVectorParam("which_stocks", len = max_stocks, lower = 1, upper = ncol(quarter.pool))), 
                                     noisy = FALSE, 
                                     vectorized = FALSE,
                                     has.simple.signature = FALSE
                                     )

ctrl <-  makeMBOControl(final.method = "best.true.y", propose.points = 1)
ctrl <- setMBOControlTermination(ctrl, iters = 10, target.fun.value = 0.0000001)

run <- mbo(fun = obj_f, control = ctrl)

obj_func(list(stock_weights = run$x$stock_weights, which_stocks = run$x$which_stocks)) == run$y
```

What happened is that stock_weights and which_stocks got combined (by `unlist()`) into one vector and passed to your `obj_func`, which unfortunately did also work even if the second argument (`which_stocks`) is not defined and the first vector was too long. This should be a reminder to always add some feasibility checks to function arguments if the function is a bit more complex. You could do so by using the `checkmate` package. Basically you did not optimize the true objective function.